# How to bind to parent position changes in WPF using XAML and no code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, canvas, position

I have a visio-like interfact but have actual model data behind some of the elements. The elements can be moved by the user.

I use a contentcontrol on a canvas whereby the viewmodels of the elements are places in the content which can then be displayed differently depending on their type but using the same contentcontrol. It is simple to bind the view to the different properties in the viewmodel. However, I have to save the position in the model, and I cannot find a binding solution.

1) The Application.Save Command is handled in the main view model, so I do not have access to the view there. That means I must save the postion data when the elements are moved, or is there a better approach?

2) Assuming that I am right with 1), I am looking to avoid code behind, i.e. I do not want the contentcontrol to deal with the elements that they have in their content. However, so far the code behind version is all I could come up with:

My code behind solution so far:

All model elements implement an interface:

```
public interface IViewElement
{
    String Position { get; set; }
}
```

And in the contentcontrol:

```
 void ContentControl_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IViewElement content = this.Content as IViewElement;
        content.Position = new Point(Diagram.GetLeft(this), Diagram.GetTop(this)).ToString();
    }
```

The XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type diagram:Item}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type diagram:Item}">
                <Grid Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=PART_ContentPresenter, Path=Content.Position, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    ContextMenu="{x:Null}">
                    <!-- PART_ContentPresenter -->
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentPresenter"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">
<StackPanel>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Can you include your XAML up to and including the Canvas tag?

Answer (score 1):

Just encapsulate the codebehind you've used in a Behavior

Comment: Thanks, was not thinking about behaviours in this case, will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a string to store the position? Use either a Point or two decimal values, and then bind your ContentControl's `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` position to these values using two-way binding.

It will automatically update the model when the Top and Left positions change.

**Edit:**
Here's an example:

```
<ContentControl Canvas.Top="{Binding ContentModel.Top, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Canvas.Left="{Binding ContentModel.Left, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Content="{Binding ContentModel}" />
```

Comment: I did not want to use Point in the model classes, and there is the PointConverter. For the Canvas.Top/Left scenario the two decimals might be the better choice.

Comment: @PatrickS I did something similar recently and each of my Panel's Models for the canvas contained properties for Top and Left. It worked out great, but be careful for window resizes. In my case the Top/Left properties were actually a percentage, so everything would get repositioned appropriately when the window got resized.

Comment: Rachel, I am still not sure how to bind a postion property of a contentcontrol's content (a viewmodel in the presenter and represented by a datatemplate) to its parent canvas.left/top

Comment: Hi, I added some code myself in trying to illustrate the problem. The contentcontrol is styled and I need to bind the content control canvas.top/left with the contents (viewmodel) Position property. The Viewmodels are presented by the contentpresenter and styled by a datatemplate. I do not get a binding error, but the Position property value is never updated. At the moment I do not see a solution without using code behind or a Behaviour.

Comment: @PatrickS Use a tool like Snoop to find out what element is the first child element within the Canvas. That is the element you need to bind Top/Left on, not your Grid. I suspect you have something at a higher level in the Canvas than the grid which is why Top/Left isn't working.

Comment: It's a Prism application, so Snoop does not help. The items are the first children on the canvas, so I am not sure what is between the grid of the controltemplate and the canvas, nothing when I do up the visualtree at least. Also, the items have a thumb which I use to catch movements and update the item postions (Canvas.SetLeft(item, left+delta). The layoutupdate event has "null" as sender. Binding to the thumb position does not work either.

Comment: @PatrickS Snoop should still show you the XAML of your application after it is rendered. Website is http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ if you need it. Can you post your full XAML that includes the Canvas element?